# is it safer to just not install flash player on Windows?

Tags: windows, firefox, flash, plugins, flash-player

I have a laptop that I use strictly for financial software and logins.  None of the websites I use on this laptop require Flash player.  I use my other laptops for browsing and extracurricular websites.  Is it safer to NOT install the Flash Player plugin on Firefox?  (I don't use Chrome).

I figure why add additional plugins if I don't need it.  Am I deluding myself?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Don't install it.  If you don't need it why install it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the confirmation!  Really appreciate it!

Comment: How is my question primarily opinion-based?  Sorry, I'm new to this forum.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need it, don't install it. That goes the same for any other software. This reduces the attack vector (same as not installing Java if you don't need it).